# Can you create on the fly references to JCheckBox objects?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcheckbox

I am not sure how to ask this. The program I am working on is done, but it seems like it has excessive code. Here is part of the code:

```
chkDef1 = new JCheckBox

if (chkDef1.isSelected()) {
            actual = chkDef1.getText();
        } 
else if (chkDef2.isSelected()) {
            actual = chkDef2.getText();
        } 
else if (chkDef3.isSelected()) {
            actual = chkDef3.getText();
        } 
else {
            actual = chkDef4.getText();
        }
```

There are other areas where there is a lot of duplicate code with the chkDef1 - 4 checkboxes. What I would like to do is use a loop in the areas where the code is duplicated and then just use 1 assignment statement.

I've tried :
    if(('chkDef' + counter).isSelected())

I've also tried assigning "'chkDef' + counter" to a String variable and then adding isSelected. Unfortunately I keep getting error messages.

I am a novice programmer so I do not know if what I want to do is possible or what it is called. If it is possible an explanation of how would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a list of `checkboxes` and iterate through it.

```
ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxes  = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
//Init your checkboxes array. 

for(JCheckbox chkbox :checkboxes)
{
  if(chkbox.isSelected())
   {
    actual = chkbox.getText() ; break;
  }
}
```

Although,  there could be a JCheckbox group that does what you want.

[Looks like you can use ButtonGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html) and get the elements to iterate through it.

Comment: +1 for the button group (although I'd recommend `JRadioButton` or `JToggledButton` for button groups from a useability perspective)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do have them as part of a button group. I'll start with the array as I understand how that works and then work on using the button group.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array that contains all the check boxes and then loop through the array...

```
JCheckBox[] boxes = new JCheckBox[] {chkDef1,chkDef2,chkDef3,chkDef4}
for (JCheckBox box : boxes) {
    if (box.isSelected()) {
        actual = box.getText();
        break; // We don't want to loop unnecessarily
    }
}
```

Equally, you could create a simple method that takes a variable number of arguments...

```
public String getCheckedItem(JCheckBox... boxes) {
    String actual = null;
    for (JCheckBox box : boxes) {
        if (box.isSelected()) {
            actual = box.getText();
            break; // We don't want to loop unnecessarily
        }
    }
    return actual;
}
```

And call it like...

```
String actual = getCheckItem(chkDef1, chkDef2, chkDef3, chkDef4);
```

Personally, I'd return the check box, but that's up to you

If you're only interested in maintaining a single selected check box (ie not allowing multiple check boxes to be selected) then you should seriously consider using `JRadioButton`s and `ButtonGroup` instead.

Otherwise you could collect ALL the selected checked boxes...

```
public JCheckBox[] getCheckedItem(JCheckBox... boxes) {
    List<JCheckBox> selected = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>(boxes.length);
    for (JCheckBox box : boxes) {
        if (box.isSelected()) {
            selected.add(box);
        }
    }
    return selected.toArray(new JCheckBox[selected.size]);
}
```